# NaN output in html but proper output shows on console

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I've got this code I'm trying to implement. However I get an odd thing that happens. In my console when I log the data it shows proper value for example 4 but when I output it into my html it show NAN. I am using ajax and PHP.

NAN output in HTML. Using PHP I'm retrieving the variable via the POST super global but why is it showing two different outputs?

```
  $.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'ajax.php',
  data:  { id: 89},
 success: function(result) {
 $('#results').html(result);
 console.log(result);
  },
 error: function() {
alert('Some error found. Please try again!');
 }
  });
```

//on the same PHP I'm calling it

```
 <?php
      if(isset($_POST['id'])) {
      $data = $_POST['id'];
  $data = floatval($data);
  echo $data;
 }
 ?>
```

I expect the output to be 89 but the value it shows in my html is NAN and in the console the data shows the correct value of 89

Comment: [Cannot reproduce using a mocked-up API endpoint](https://jsfiddle.net/e2qx45pw/). Please provide sample HTTP request/response data from your endpoint.

Comment: the key parts of your code in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gekvy31u/) show that the code you posted will not behave that way ... ever

Comment: I DONT understand, it prints out in console but not HTML?

Answer (score -1):

i think you need json response for this you need

echo json_encode($data);